# Why can not add the build version in iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to upload the iOS App to Apple Store. And I have upload my code by Xcode 7.

But in the iTunes connect. I can not select my uplaod version because I did not see the "add" button of "build version". Like the following picture.
[image]

Did I missing something ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it some time, there's definitely a delay. I've experienced delays of up to one hour before I saw the button appear to select a build.  If Xcode 7 indicated that the application was successfully submitted, it sounds like you've done everything correct.  Just wait a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

We haven't been able to submit the app for review cause Apple's upload process is broken since about 3pm PDT Thursday. I got it to upload but can't release through Testflight or directly to Apple for App store review.  Sadly, there isnt much we can do. We're in wait and wait mode.

Found this on the forums
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25384

This is what their broken controls webpage looks like :-(
[image: TestFlight broken controls]