# Cannot Submit my build to Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have been trying to submit my app to being reviewed, and I have gone to Xcode 7(newest version at the time of writing) and I validated and tried to submit it. However at the end, after it validates, it gives this warning.

[image: Warning]

And apparently you can still complete the submission but, when I go to iTunes connect, it still shows this:

[image: iTC screenshot]

What should I do, is it the warning that is the problem, does it take time to come up, it has been an hour and it is a fairly small app. Or is it something else? E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search, there are lots of similar posts. for example: [Itunes Connect: Can't See Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674742/itunes-connect-cant-see-build?rq=1) or [Why can not add the build version in iTunes connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568965/why-can-not-add-the-build-version-in-itunes-connect)

It takes time for the build to display in iTunes Connect. Sometimes minutes. sometimes hours. if the next day, I would resubmit with a new build number or call. it is confusing your first time and I wish Apple was more informative.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mark's answer but still we can see the progressing status on iTunes connect after upload.

Follow below steps :

> - Login to iTunes Connect
> - Select your application
> - Then select the Activity tab(last tab). Over there you will be able      to see the build with Progressing status.

Hope it helps you.